# Freeswitch Play a sound in ring group when brigde multi call

Tags: freeswitch

Im using freeswitch to build our PBX.
My case when have incomming call to a ring group with strategy is rollover, i want to play just one ringtone file when call bridge from user A->B->C in ring group.
Currently if i set that"

```
session:setVariable("ringback", ring_group_ringback);       
session:setVariable("transfer_ringback", ring_group_ringback);

session:preAnswer();
```

The ring will reset after bridge new extension to call

I had tried to using uuid_displace but it not playsound

im using version freeswitch v1.10.8

Please help

Comment: Try to set ringback in the bridge line.

Comment: Thanks @HP371 i still don't understand, can you give more clearly suggest, i mean i want an audio ringback ring continue not reset after move to next bridge